# PL/SQL Block Function & Test

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

EDIT:
Seem to have sorted it, think it was just a problem with my table inserts.

Okay so I am pretty new to PL/SQL so be easy on me but I have this code I have to write where I have to check the category of a book and if it return true I will have a test that will insert a row. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this? Thanks. The function executes correctly but I'm not entirely sure it is  correct in its syntax and its just the test that is giving me the error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CheckBookType (
  p_Type    titles.category%TYPE)
  RETURN BOOLEAN IS

  v_ReturnValue     BOOLEAN;
BEGIN

  IF (p_Type) = 'business' THEN
    v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  ELSIF (p_Type) = 'psychology' THEN
    v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  ELSIF (p_Type) = 'mod_cook' THEN
    v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  ELSIF (p_Type) = 'trad_cook' THEN
    v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  ELSIF (p_Type) = 'popular_comp' THEN
    v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  ELSE
    v_ReturnValue := FALSE;
  END IF;

  RETURN v_ReturnValue;
END CheckBookType;

set serveroutput on;
BEGIN
  IF(CheckBookType('psychology'))=true THEN
    INSERT INTO Titles VALUES(1234, 'test', 'psychology', sysdate, 1234);
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid');
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you've already resolved this, and that's good.  But here's another suggestion for your IF statement.  If setting v_ReturnValue to TRUE is all you're doing in the IF statement then you can significantly shorten it as follows:

```
v_ReturnValue := FALSE;  -- Or better yet, initialize it to FALSE in the declaration
IF p_Type IN ('business', 'psychology', 'mod_cook', 'trad_cook', 'popular_comp') THEN
  v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
END IF;
```

The downside to this is if at some point you need to do more than just set v_ReturnValue to TRUE for only some of those values of p_Type, then you'll need to expand the IF statement again.  On the other hand, this is a lot shorter and it's easier to add or remove values of p_Type for which you want v_ReturnValue to be TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK to me at first glance.
However, I would suggest using a CASE statement instead of multiple IF-THEN-ELSE statements:

```
CASE p_Type
  WHEN 'business' THEN v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  WHEN 'psychology' THEN v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  WHEN 'mod_cook' THEN v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  WHEN 'trad_cook' THEN v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  WHEN 'popular_comp' THEN v_ReturnValue := TRUE;
  ELSE  v_ReturnValue := FALSE;
END CASE
```

I've written about the [CASE statement before](http://www.databasestar.com/oracle-case-statement/), which can be used in both SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: Yeah, everything appears to be okay now I just had to sort something out with the tables and thanks they seem a lot less effort than writing IF's constantly.